# setInputValue in shiny application only responding in text output, not in observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am building an application that should be able to store locations that users enter in a dashboard (such that other users across sessions can relate to the same data). I use a shiny application with an `ActionButton` ('save') that users can click on. The data is saved in a CSV file on the server, and other users can load that data using a `reactiveFileReader`.

The locations are split into two blocks: One block for the current set of locations, and another for the locations that have been added in this session (before saving). If a user hits the save button, all the inputs belonging to the added locations are removed and the file reader is invoked, such that these locations are now part of the current set of locations.

Now my problem: If I add a location, hit the save button, and then try to add a location again, the app crashes. Even though in the `renderText` at the bottom of my app, the value of the `ActionButton` is 0, if I debug my session the error is clearly related to the `ActionButton` not being reset (the value is 2, yet it should be 1). How is this possible?

If anything is unclear please let me know.

I use `shiny 1.6.0`, `R 4.0.3` and `shinyjs 2.0.0`

See my code and the CSV file below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)


# User interface for the locations input
TestUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),
    
    # Action button to save the parameters ----
    actionButton(inputId = ns("save"),
                 label = "Save locations"),
    
    # Input: Text field and action button to add test street ----
    textInput(inputId = ns("location_name"),
              label = "Location name:"),
    actionButton(inputId = ns("add_location"),
                 label = "Add location"),
    div(id='add'),
    
    # User interface for already existing locations ----
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("locations")),
    
    # User interface for the locations that are added by the user ----
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("locations_added")),
    
    # textoutput
    textOutput(outputId = ns("counter"))
  )
}

# Server side for the locations input
TestServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # Create namespace functions
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # Set the filenames
      fn_locations <- "store/populations.csv"
      
      # What is the last time this file was saved and load the file
      input_matrix <- reactiveFileReader(5000, session, fn_locations, read.csv2)
      
      # Store the names of the locations
      location_names <- reactiveValues()
      
      # Add input fields for the already existing locations from the file
      output$locations <- renderUI({
        
        if(nrow(input_matrix()) > 0){
          
          input_list <- lapply(1:nrow(input_matrix()), function(i) {
            
            location_names[[paste0(i)]] <- input_matrix()[i,1]
            
            wellPanel(
              fluidRow(
                column(12, titlePanel(input_matrix()[i,1]))
              ),
              fluidRow(
                column(2,                 
                       numericInput(inputId = ns(paste0("population_", i)),
                                    label = "Population",
                                    min = 0,
                                    step = 1,
                                    value = input_matrix()[i,2])),
                column(1,
                       checkboxInput(inputId = ns(paste0("save_", i)),
                                     label = "Opslaan",
                                     value = TRUE))
              )
            )
          })
        } else{
          input_list <- list(wellPanel(tags$h4("No locations have been saved")))
        }
        
        do.call(tagList, input_list)
      })
      
      # List for the UI's with the added locations
      added_input_list <- list()
      
      # Add an UI for a new location ----
      observeEvent(input$add_location, {
        
        if(input$add_location > 0){
          
          input_list <- lapply(1:input$add_location, function(i) {
            
            if(i == input$add_location){
              location_names[[paste0(nrow(input_matrix()) + i)]] <- input$location_name
            }
            
            wellPanel(
              fluidRow(
                column(12, titlePanel(location_names[[paste0(nrow(input_matrix()) + i)]])
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(2,                 
                         numericInput(inputId = ns(paste0("population_",nrow(input_matrix()) + i)),
                                      label = "Population",
                                      min = 0,
                                      step = 1,
                                      value = ifelse(i == input$add_location, 0, input[[paste0("population_", nrow(input_matrix()) + i)]]))),
                  column(1,
                         checkboxInput(inputId = ns(paste0("save_", nrow(input_matrix()) + i)),
                                       label = "Opslaan",
                                       value = ifelse(i == input$add_location, TRUE, input[[paste0("save_", nrow(input_matrix()) +  i)]])))
                )
              )
            )
          })
          
          output$locations_added <- renderUI({
            do.call(tagList, input_list)
          })
        }
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$save, {
          # Which elements should be saved?
          savers <- sapply(paste0("save_", 1:(nrow(input_matrix()) + input$add_location)), function(x) input[[x]])
          
          to_write_matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = sum(savers), ncol = 2)
          i <- 1
          j <- 1
          
          while(i <= sum(savers)){
            
            # Only save the rows for which the save option was TRUE
            if(input[[paste0("save_",j)]]){
              row_i <- c(location_names[[paste0(j)]],
                         input[[paste0("population_", j)]])
              
              to_write_matrix[i, ] <- row_i
              i <- i + 1
            }
            j <- j + 1
          }
          
          while(i <= length(reactiveValuesToList(location_names))){
            
            # Use shinyJS to remove these inputs starting from i
            runjs(paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('",ns(paste0("population_",i)),"',null)"))
            runjs(paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('",ns(paste0("save_",i)),"',null)"))
            i <- i + 1
          }
          
          # Write the locations to a file
          write.csv2(to_write_matrix, file = fn_locations, row.names=FALSE)
          
          # Remove the old added locations
          runjs(paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('",ns("add_location"),"',0)"))
          output$locations_added <- NULL
          
          # Show notification that the save was successfull
          showNotification("The locations have been saved")
      })
      
      output$counter <- renderText(input$add_location)
    }
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", icon = icon("signal"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard", TestUI(id = "locations"))
    )
  ),
  
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  TestServer("locations")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
"V1";"V2"
"Amsterdam";"800000"
"Brussels";"700000"
"Berlin";"1500000"
```

Comment: Please attach the csv file you're loading

Comment: It is there, at the bottom of the post

Comment: Note: I strongly suggest storing the data in a database (such as SQLite) instead of a text file. If two users access a text file at the same time there is a possibility of corruption. A database is built to handle this.

Comment: I know, my real application has indeed a SQLite database to store the data.

Comment: This hardly looks like a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If you have a better implementation of what I am trying to do, feel free to share it ;)